# Modeling a 2D Table in PostgreSQL (Django)

Tags: python, sql, django, database, postgresql

So I'd like to model a 2D table in PostgreSQL, and by 2D I mean I'd like to add/update/delete both rows and columns. Before I really get into the details I wanted to convey that I did look into dynamic Django models such that I could extend models and add columns during runtime but to be honest it does seem like kind of a hack job, and none of those packages have good docs or is maintained as of now for the latest version of Django and Python. NoSQL is kinda a stretch to switch too this late in the game and eliminates many of the useful features of Django such as the ORM and model integration with DRF.

[image]

For example in this table, I have some required fields such as firmware name to which I might add publish date or build number or something of the sort. But I also have column headers which may be added or removed as new software versions are released, for example 4.0.1. Is there such a way of modeling this to optimally create a CRUD API that avoids unnecessary redundancy?

As of now, I basically have the following models, but of course storing the release number multiple times creates redundancy for every column. Also makes the frontend UI very convoluted because I have to click into a row and basically edit each support value one by one in a modal which in terms of UX makes no sense. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

- Table   (title, footnotes)
- Row     (name, date, build, etc, FK to Table)
- Support (release, value, FK to Row)

Comment: Have you considered using a JSON field? If you are using Postgres it's certainly an option (it appears MySQL also has a JSON field, but I do not have experience with it). It gives you the flexibility of NoSQL while still retaining some Django ORM querying ability on the data within the field. I think if I were tackling this problem that is probably the first thing I'd experiment with.

Comment: I did look into it but it seems to me in terms of writing an API it would be no different from switching to NoSQL in terms of complexity, and would be equally as redundant. It probably wouldn't maintain order of the keys given that it's JSON as well.

Comment: Yeah. I think something like what lorg suggests below is probably the best bet then.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely solution is to model it using two models and a many-to-many relationship between them. E.g. version <-> firmware name, if I understand your example correctly.

So to be more concrete - have a Firmware table, have a Version table, and a join table FirmwareVersion with foreign keys to both. You will also want to add additional fields on the join table, such as a support enum.

This way you can easily add more firmwares and more versions.

Some pseudocode:

```
class Firmware(Model):
    name = StringField()

class Version(Model):
    name = StringField()

class FirmwareVersion(Model):
    firmware = ForeignKey(Firmware)
    version = ForeignKey(Version)
    support = EnumField(["y", "n", "c"])
```

Comment: I would expect that when you add a new version or firmware, it will add default values for all existing firmwares or versions accordingly, which then you could edit.

Comment: Consider a similar example - when you have users and repositories and a join table with permissions. What happens when you add a new one of either?

Take a look at e.g. GitHub API to see a good implementation of such a thing, or other similar many to many relationships.

Comment: Hmmmm I suppose, but that would mean a lot of work on the APIs instead of using ModelViewset and have them generated for me

Comment: If this is effectively a many to many, then why use a through table?

Comment: All many to many uses a through table behind the scenes. Reasons to model it yourself:
1. You need an additional field on that table
2. My *personal preference* is usually to prefer explicit over implicit in this case
3. If you decide to change later to a table you manage yourself, you'll need a more complex schema migration because of how django manages primary keys.

Comment: Last thing: take a look at SO answers on "how to model many to many with viewsets": https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+model+many+to+many+modelviewset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209259/discussion-between-malik-brahimi-and-lorg).